# ifup returns an unknown interface error

Tags: network-manager, connection, network-bridge, virtualbox-networking, ip-address

I'm still learning Linux and I'm less familiar with Ubuntu. I have a Ubuntu image that I'm using in VirtualBox on a windows machine. It was able to connect and get an IP address up until about a week ago. I made no configuration changes. I've tried placing VirtualBox settings to use NAT and also tried bridged, it didn't seem to make a difference. If I run ifconfig, it gives me enp0s3, but if I run ifup enp0s3 I get an unknown interface enp0s3 error.

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux cs165-VirtualBox 4.10.0-40-generic #44-16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 15:33:07 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

`ifconfig` output:

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:eb:53:a4
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:720 (720.0 B)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:240 (240.0 B)  TX bytes:240 (240.0 B)
```

What I get when I try to restart the network service:

```
~> /etc/init.d/networking restart
[ ok ] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service.
```

`ifup` returns an unknown interface error:

```
~> ifup enp0s3
Unknown interface enp0s3
```

Comment: Just as an FYI for the future, please don't put screenshots of terminal output into a post, instead consider copying/pasting the actual terminal output into a code-formatted block in your question itself.

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s3 up
```

or

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s3 down
```

or

```
sudo ip link set dev enp0s3 up
```

or

```
sudo ip link set dev enp0s3 down
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: None of them worked, thanks for the advice though.

Comment: @MariahAshley I get the exact same error if I run the `ifup` command on my eth0 card that I know is working.  The commands in this answer are the correct ones to run to bring the interface up and down.   You might be having an issue with VirtualBox itself.  Maybe try reinstalling VirtualBox, you shouldn't lose any of your VMs, unless you tell the uninstall to remove everything.  Also, check to make sure that the Guest Additions to VirtualBox are up to date.

Comment: @MariahAshley, did you figure this out? I am having exactly the same problem. Also on virtualbox on windows 10. this was working 2 days back

Comment: @alpha_989 did you somehow resolve it? I have exactly the same issue,

Answer (score 0):

I have tried refreshing the MAC address on my virtual machine and it works.